# Unwrapping of symmetric key throws Pkcs11Exception / CKR_GENERAL_ERROR

Tags: pkcs#11, pkcs11interop, softhsm

I'm trying to convert the [Wrap / Unwrap example](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop/blob/master/src/Pkcs11Interop.Tests/HighLevelAPI/_24_WrapAndUnwrapKeyTest.cs) from a RSA key pair to a single AES key:

```cs
// Open RW session
using (ISession session = slot.OpenSession(SessionType.ReadWrite))
{
  string userPin = "1234";

  // Login as normal user
  session.Login(CKU.CKU_USER, userPin);

  // Generate symetric secret key
  IObjectHandle secretKey = Helpers.GenerateKey(session);

  // Generate symetric key
  IObjectHandle publicKey = Helpers.GenerateKey(session);

  // Specify wrapping mechanism
  IMechanism mechanism = session.Factories.MechanismFactory.Create(CKM.CKM_AES_KEY_WRAP);

  // Wrap key
  byte[] wrappedKey = session.WrapKey(mechanism, publicKey, secretKey);

  // Define attributes for unwrapped key
  List<IObjectAttribute> objectAttributes = new List<IObjectAttribute>();

  objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_CLASS, CKO.CKO_SECRET_KEY));
  objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_KEY_TYPE, CKK.CKK_AES));
  objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_ENCRYPT, true));
  objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_DECRYPT, true));
  objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_DERIVE, true));
  objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_EXTRACTABLE, true));
  objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_TOKEN, true));
  objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_LABEL, "UnWrapperTest"));

  // Unwrap key
  IObjectHandle unwrappedKey = session.UnwrapKey(mechanism, secretKey, wrappedKey, objectAttributes);
  }
}
```

with

```cs
public static IObjectHandle GenerateKey(ISession session)
{
  // Prepare attribute template of new key
  List<IObjectAttribute> objectAttributes = new List<IObjectAttribute>();
  objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_CLASS, CKO.CKO_SECRET_KEY));
  objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_KEY_TYPE, CKK.CKK_AES));
  objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_TOKEN, true));
  objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_ENCRYPT, true));
  objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_DECRYPT, true));
  objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_DERIVE, true));
  objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_EXTRACTABLE, true));
  objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_VALUE_LEN, 32));
  objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_LABEL, "WrapperTest"));

  // Specify key generation mechanism
  IMechanism mechanism = session.Factories.MechanismFactory.Create(CKM.CKM_AES_KEY_GEN);

  // Generate key
  return session.GenerateKey(mechanism, objectAttributes);
}
```

But the line `IObjectHandle unwrappedKey = session.UnwrapKey(mechanism, secretKey, wrappedKey, objectAttributes);` always throws a `Net.Pkcs11Interop.Common.Pkcs11Exception: 'Method C_UnwrapKey returned CKR_GENERAL_ERROR'` exception.

As 'HSM' I'm using a [SoftHSM2 on Windows](https://github.com/disig/SoftHSM2-for-Windows).

What am I doing wrong?

**Disclosure:** I'm cross-posting this question also in [GitHub](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop/issues/131)

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem:

`IObjectHandle unwrappedKey = session.UnwrapKey(mechanism, secretKey, wrappedKey, objectAttributes);`

should read

`IObjectHandle unwrappedKey = session.UnwrapKey(mechanism, publicKey, wrappedKey, objectAttributes);`